# gRPC server to start on specific IP Address

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

how can I start gRPC server on some specific IP address?
In every tutorial I found (used and tested) this:

```
    Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(50051)
            .addService(new GreetServiceImpl().)
            .build();

    server.start();
```

But I need to specify not just port but full address:
Something like this (non-existing code):

```
    Server server = ServerBuilder.forAddress(154.45.153.1)forPort(50051)
            .addService(new GreetServiceImpl().)
            .build();

    server.start();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found solution that works:

```
    Server server;

    SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.150.116", 5085);
    server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(address).addService(new GreetServiceImpl()).build();

    server.start();
```

I do not know if there is some drawback with this approach.

Comment: That is the solution I would suggest. The only real drawback is you need to use the grpc-netty API directly.